# Why indexes don't speed up this query?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

I have two tables `users` and `posts` with 500k records each.

I want to find users who had written between 100 and 200 posts.

My query is:

```
SELECT u.accountid, COUNT(*)
FROM users u
JOIN posts p
ON u.accountid = p.owneruserid
GROUP BY u.accountid
HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
```

And I get answer in about a second.

I added indexes on `accountid` and `owneruserid` fields in tables `users` and `posts` respectively but the query didn't speed up. Why?

Comment: 1 second seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: explain analyze

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's only for tests. I just don't get why indexes didn't help at all

Comment: Indexes are mainly about efficiently getting a subset of the data.  But it looks like your query needs to get and process all of the data (only subsetting after the grouping operation occurs).  So it's not surprising that an index wouldn't help.

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm gonna check it

Comment: please posts them :) not just check

Comment: @VaoTsun Of course :)

Comment: @VaoTsun Explain analyze [without indexes](https://pastebin.com/raw/Xfu0Xd3Z) and [with indexes](https://pastebin.com/raw/vTdgp4BH)

Comment: but according to them difference is 10 times? 1.3 sec and 15 sec

Comment: @VaoTsun Don't know why. Without explain it take 1.2-1.4 second

Comment: just select is faster then explain analyze select?.. unbelievable postgres analyzes anyway before select, `explain ` just instructs it to show the result of analyze

Comment: @VaoTsun I re-run this explain analyze and got 1.3 sec. Probably PC was doing something else on first try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144554/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-user4230877).

Comment: @VaoTsun [without indexes take two](https://pastebin.com/raw/JP7hAHwa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
```

The part is key to explain why indexes are futile.

We need to get only groups where member count between 100 and 200. It means for each group we need exact count of members. The second point we don't have any restrictions (e.g. WHERE section) so to get counts and all groups we need to go through all the records in the table.

Indexes e.g. B-Tree index help to find proper element (row) based on index condition. If data is somehow ordered (index provides the order) we can use binary search to find desired subset. But in our case we need to scan all records. So it does not matter whether they ordered or not.

That's why index does not speed up the query.

Comment: Answer I needed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT p.owneruserid, COUNT(*)
FROM posts p
GROUP BY p.owneruserid
HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
```

The index on `posts(owneruserid)` should work for this query.  It is a covering index for the query, so the query might be a wee bit faster.

Overall, the query seems to require scanning all the data in `posts` for the aggregation.  The `HAVING` cannot take advantage of an index.  However, the query can use the covering index to reduce I/O.

Comment: It could bring incorrect results, IF there're data discrepancies. But then OP has more problems.

Comment: Index won't work anyway. It requests `HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 100 AND 200` which requires full scan to have all counts.

Comment: But if he would put results of count in temp table, and then count between 100 and 200 ... would that work faster then Having count clause? never tested that so had to ask

Comment: It's true it can be simplified but this is not the whole query. I need some fields from `users` but I erased them for this question to make it more clear. Maybe needlessly.

Comment: @StanislavL Could you tell something more about it? Point some source?

Comment: @user4230877 could you use this simplified version and join the user table aftwards?

Comment: @MalteHartwig Unfortunately it must be this very query

Comment: @user4230877, Stanislav means that indexes help you when you look for some entries in the table based on the indexed columns. But in order to group by id with having count, you need to retrieve **all** entries, which will not be faster. Imagine a library: Finding a book by author is fast because they put authors in different shelves. But if you want to know how many books each author wrote, you still have to touch **every single** book. The fact that they are ordered/indexed by auther does not help. It dos help if you only want to know how many books one specific author wrote, though.

Comment: @MalteHartwig  . . . Ironically, your example also explains how indexes can be used for group by. If you want to count the number of books each author has written, it can be simpler to go through the card-catalog than to look at the books on the shelves.  Of course, how many people reading this forum have ever seen a physical card catalog in a library?

Comment: @MalteHartwig OK. In mongoDB index helped a lot (same data and query). It looks like in this particular example this databases differs

Comment: @GordonLinoff, true that, using the index for counting might help. It's not that easy to come up with analogies :/ But I guess Stanislav has elaborated a bit himself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44047135/7653073